# Google Play Games not allowing user to join turn-based match

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-play-services, google-play-games

I create a turn-based match and proceed to invite a single opponent as follows:

```
GPGMultiplayerConfig *config = [[GPGMultiplayerConfig alloc] init];
// We will automatically match with one other player
config.invitedPlayerIds = @[self.opponent.googlePlayID];
config.minAutoMatchingPlayers = 0;
config.maxAutoMatchingPlayers = 0;

[GPGTurnBasedMatch
 createMatchWithConfig:config
 completionHandler:^(GPGTurnBasedMatch *match, NSError *error) {
     if (error) {
         completion(NO);
         return;
     }
}];
```

After this device places the first move and passes the next turn to my opponent device, my opponent device receives the push notification to join the match. I respond by joining. At this point my `self.match.userMatchStatus` for this invited device is `invited`:

```
[self.match joinWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        completion(NO);
        return;
    }
}];
```

This doesn't give an error. Upon calling `self.match.isMyTurn`, I get back `YES`. A call to `self.match.userMatchStatus` gives the status of `invited`; not `joined`. The documentation (which is incredibly poor, by the way) states that this `joinWithCompletionHandler:` method:

> Joins a turn-based match that the player has been invited to.

Even when adding a dispatch time delay in of 3 seconds after this, to give it a chance, I find that it's still set to `invited`. Calling further methods, such as `takeTurnWithNextParticipantId:data:results:completionHandler:`, fails with an entirely undocumented error:

> Error Domain=com.google.GooglePlayGames Code=3 "The operation couldn’t
>   be completed. (com.google.GooglePlayGames error 3.)"

Here's a link to Google's documentation:

https://developers.google.com/games/services/ios/api/interface_g_p_g_turn_based_match

Comment: I'm having the same error, can't determine what's going on, have you had any success in resolving it?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are passing the player id instead of participant id to takeTurnWithNextParticipantId. The error code 3 (and http response code 400) means that something in passed parameters is invalid, in my case it was the participant id which i had set wrong.