# Taking turn in Turn Based Game on Google Play Games for iOS gives "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.GooglePlayGames error 3.)"

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-play, google-play-services

I'm at the point now where a player invited to a Turn-Based Match has the `match.myStatus` of `GPGTurnBasedParticipantStatusJoined`, `match.userMatchStatus` of `GPGTurnBasedUserMatchStatusTurn`, and `match.isMyTurn` of `YES`. Yet when they call this method:

```
[self.match
 takeTurnWithNextParticipantId:nextParticipantID
 data:[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:@{@"A test": @"My test"} options:0 error:nil]
 results:nil
 completionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
     NSLog(@"took turn with error: %@, data: %i", error, self.match.data.length);
     if (error) {
         return;
     }

     //Continue
 }];
```

They get this error:

> Error Domain=com.google.GooglePlayGames Code=3 "The operation couldn’t
>   be completed. (com.google.GooglePlayGames error 3.)"

This error is entirely undocumented on Google's part. I have no indication of what the issue is, or what I could be doing wrong, considering everything points to the code above being correct.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you pass the participant id, not the player id! See also the answer of your other post: [Google Play Games not allowing user to join turn-based match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24749945/google-play-games-not-allowing-user-to-join-turn-based-match)